# Why would logback ever READ the log file it is writing to?

Tags: java, append, logback

In a java application that uses logback, and runs under Windows 7, the sysinternals process monitor (www.sysinternals.com) shows that the java process is READING the application's log file.  Why would this be?

Our app is having issues and logback came under scrutiny when this was discovered.  We have since found that this is irrelevant to our issues, but I would still like to understand it.

I had thought that an appender would only append to the end of the log file as its name implies and am surprised and embarrassed to see this, especially after I insisted it couldn't be possibly be true.

Can someone explain why logback would need to READ a logfile?  I can categorically state that none of the **application's** code reads the file.

Comment: What about a rolling file appender? Wouldn't that imply that the appender also has to remove data from the beginning of the file? And even more: read the data it removes to write it into the next file (like log.1).

Comment: I wouldn't think so.  I would think that the application would know what time it was, know the name of the current logfile and the date of the last entry, and based on those three bits of information either 1) append to the current file or 2) create a new file as appropriate.  I don't see why that would necessitate a read.